# How to retrieve data from the string.xml file in to the android application?

Tags: android

I am new to the android application to develop a project. There is a **string.xml** file in my project. My question is how to retrieve the data from the **string.xml**?

Answer (score 0):

```
String string =  context.getString(R.string.string_name);
```

or

```
String string =  this.getString(R.string.string_name);
```

Take a look at [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myString = getResources().getString(R.string.stringname);
```

**and if it is String array**

```
String[] stringArray ;
stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stringArrayName);
```